# Restore the keyboard when you rotate the screen

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I restore the keyboard:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mMessageFragmentPresenter.getVisibleKeyBoard()){
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    } else {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

On android api 22 works fine. But on the android api > 24, when you go to the horizontal position, the keyboard is not shown. How can I fix this?